# Check if it is a geometric series?

Tags: python

I need some help in checking if "il" is a geometric series, 
if yes: 
   print True and in the raw below the ratio. 
if not 
   print: false. 
if the list has only one term print:￼￼￼ only one member.

**Eg:-**

il = [2,4,8]
output will be: True and in the row below 2.

il = [2,4,20] 
output will be: False.

il = [2], output will be: only one number.

the problem with what I did is that the output for the option: the list has only one term isn't right.

My Approach

```
il = [2]
def is_geometric(li):
    while len(li) <= 1:
        print ('only one number')
        break
    while len(li) > 1:
        ratio = li[1]/float(li[0]) # Check the ratio of the remaining
        for i in range(1, len(li)):
            if li[i]/float(li[i-1]) != ratio:
                return False
            return True
print (is_geometric(il))
```

The output it gives: "only one number" and in the row below "None"

I don't understand why it's giving back "None"

Answer (score 0):

A bit polished up:

```
il = [2,4,8]

def is_geometric(li):

    if len(li) <= 1:    
        print ('only one number')    
        return True

    else:    
        ratio = li[1]/float(li[0]) # Check the ratio of the remaining

        for i in range(1, len(li)):    
            if li[i]/float(li[i-1]) != ratio:    
                return False

        print(ratio)    
        return True

print (is_geometric(il))
```

Comment: it's now working but the output when there is only one term isn't correct:
it is: only one number 
       True